# Returning text/plain in struts 1.x

Tags: java, ajax, jquery, struts-1

Is it possible to return a single value of type String instead of forwarding to action in struts 1.x.

I got few similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251498/1395623), and [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ajax.html).

In struts documentation they mentioned,

> Both Struts 1 and Struts 2 can return any type of response.

But in all discussions they explained for struts 2.

Can anybody help me how can i do in struts1.x?

**Update:**
Paul Vargas suggestion resolved my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have an instance of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`, you can write the text directly. e.g.:

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("We are send text plain");

        return null;
    }

}
```

With this way, you can send JSON, XML or binaries.

If you are combining *traditional* requests and Ajax (e.g., with `jQuery.ajax` ), may be you want to check for send an full HTML page or a fragment, JSON, and so on, with:

```
private final boolean isAjaxRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String header = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
    return header != null && header.equalsIgnoreCase("XMLHttpRequest");
}
```